# How to use different keyboards in different apps without paid software?

Tags: applications, keyboard, gboard

Is there a way to use different keyboards in different apps? I want to use GBoard for every app except for my Terminal, in which I want to use Hacker's Keyboard. I want to do this because GBoard is a great keyboard, but I can't use arrow keys, ctrl+c, etc.

How could I use different virtual keyboards for different apps without using paid software?

This is different from [Use fixed keyboard for a given app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35216) because the answer includes paid software.

---

I am using the OnePlus 5 with OxygenOS 4.5.10 (Stock ROM) (Based on Nougat 7.1.1)

Using this kernel: https://build.nethunter.com/nightly/3.20-20170903-2143/kernel-nethunter-oneplus5-oos-nougat-3.20-20170903-2143.zip

Rooted with Magisk [tiny.cc/latestmagisk](http://tiny.cc/latestmagisk)

Using the Kali Nethunter terminal: https://github.com/offensive-security/kali-nethunter/blob/master/nethunter-installer/update/data/app/Term-nh.apk

Kali Nethunter installed with this Magisk module: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/kali-nethunter-magisk-t3676681/page1

Comment: See: [Use fixed keyboard for a given app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35216/16575) (even the request for Hacker's Keyboard matches ;) Unfortunately, it seems that cannot be fully automated though (at least not without root).

Comment: @Izzy That looks like it would work, but I don't want to pay $2.99...

Comment: There's a 7 day trial available for Tasker to check first if it fits your needs, see our [tag:tasker] tag wiki. Apart from that, not much I can help you saving that "cup-of-coffee" tip. Of course, you could check with other [tag:automation] apps whether they can do that for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid)

Steps :-

1. Download, install and launch
2. Go to Marcos
3. Add new Marco
4. In trigger select the app launched and select the terminal app
5. In actions select Keyboard switch(i guess this would cause the keyboard list popup so you will need to tap once on hakers keyboard)
6. Repeat same for App closed trigger (add both trigger in same macro)

Hope it gets the job done

Do report back

**Update:**

Try putting constraints of app running or app in foreground on app closed action

And app not running or not in foregroung on app launched action

I would also suggest to try to keeping 2 different macros for launching and closing and also it should work without legacy support

Comment: I thought this would work, but the switch keyboard prompt keeps popping up the whole time the app is open.

Comment: Please add following info. To your question:- 
1) device name, android version 
2) rooted or not 
3) ‎link to terminal app

Comment: I got it working by enabling Force Legacy mode or something like that...

Comment: However, it appears to consume A LOT of RAM.